# How to create a dummy instance unsing jmockit?

Tags: java, constructor, jmockit

For a test I like to create a new instance of `ComplicatedClass` . In reality it's very complicated to crate this instance, but I don't need the real constructor to run nor any of it's data. All I need is an object of `ComplicatedClass`. How can I do that?

```
public class ComplicatedClass {

    public ComplicatedClass(/* lots of dependencies */) {
  }


}


@Test
public class SomeTest {

    public void test1() {

        ComplicatedClass complicatedInstance = /* new ComplicatedClass(); /*

        AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass(complicatedInstance);

        /* ... */
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Tested` annotation does this:

`@Tested ComplicatedClass complicatedInstance;`

That's it. Please note that the above won't do any mocking. It is just convenient way of creating instances without calling consturctors, etc.

If you want `ComplicatedClass` to be mocked, use `@Mocked` annotation:

`@Mocked ComplicatedClass complicatedInstance;`

In this case, you also get your instance automatically created, but the instance is mocked.

Comment: This gives this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No constructor in class `ComplicatedClass` that can be satisfied by available injectables. To me this looks like it's expecting a default constructor for `ComplicatedClass`. What I want is that it's not calling any constructor for `ComplicatedClass`

Comment: The instantiation of a `@Tested` class always uses a real constructor (which one depends on the available `@Injectable`s). For `@Mocked`, no constructor is invoked, but the whole class is mocked by default. You can, however, specify nothing to be mocked: `@Mocked("") ComplicatedClass complicatedInstance`. But this may lead to `NullPointerException`s of other failures later, since the instance was not initialized. Bottom line is, if `ComplicatedClass` is to be *tested*, then you do need to call a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

@Tested internally instantiates the class object.

But in case of Junit test case writing of singleton class how @Tested internally creates instance because for singleton private constructor is there.